# Connect to database in php and include once, but connect file not in root

Tags: php, mysql, database, include, connection

I've created a connect file, which is stored in the folder above the `wwwroot` for security reasons.

```
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DBNAME");
```

I want to include that only once in `header.php` so that it can be used globally across all files. 
I've tried:

```
   include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../connect.php')
```

However I am having to include the `connect.php` file in every single file because otherwise it says that my `$con` object is not an object. I don't know if this has something to do with variable scopes - but if I'm including the `header.php` in every other file, shouldn't it be available?
I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object

If anyone knows why it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Prefixing `$con` with global didnt fix it.
The only other code that should affect it is:

```
  <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
```

And im trying to use it in:

```
         class CommentFunctions{
    //include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../connect.php');

    public static function getUserData($userId){

        $result = $con->query("SELECT name,image
                        FROM USERS where userID =  ".$userId);
        if($result){        
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            }   
        }
        return null;
    }
```

which itself is in `includes/comments.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above $con add:

```
global $con;
```

If that doesn't help please paste a larger chunk of code.

In your updated code you have a scope issue. Add global $con inside the method and problem solved.

```
global $con;
$result = $con->query("SELECT name,image
```

Comment: @matt Please take a look at the revision